# SignatureDoesNotMatch Error when using NodeJS 'aws-sdk' in a Docker Container proxied by an external apache2 Server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, apache, proxy

i'm currently working on a NodeJs API in a Docker container using the node image. This container publishes a port and is externally proxied by an apache2 server. I tried to isolate the issue and i'm not sure why i get the error on my ubuntu Server while it works on my lokal machine.

This is my node app:

#### server.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port);

// I tried this ... :
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-central-1',
    // ... and i tried this:
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
});

app.post('/aws', async function(req, res, next) {
    // Create sendEmail params
    const params = {
        Destination: { CcAddresses: [], ToAddresses: ['mail@example.com'] },
        Message: {
            Subject: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: `AWS NodeJS Test` },
            Body: {
                Html: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: `<h3>AWS NodeJS Test</h3>` },
                Text: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: 'TEXT_FORMAT_BODY' }
            },
        },
        Source: 'mail@example.com',
        ReplyToAddresses: ['mail@example.com'],
    };
    // Create the promise and SES service object
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => new AWS.SES({
            apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
        }).sendEmail(params).promise()
            .then((data) => resolve(data))
            .catch((err) => reject(err))
    );
    if(result?.ResponseMetadata?.RequestId) {
        return res.status(200).json({success: true});
    }
    return res.status(500).json({success: false});
});
```

#### my-example.com-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost example.com:443>
    ServerName example.com

    <Location />
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

    SSLCertificateFile /#######################################
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /#######################################
    Include /#######################################
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

#### the error in my docker logs:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Comment: Can you confirm where you are getting the credentials from please? That error usually occurs when you are using credentials from STS and you used an STS endpoint in the wrong region to generate them or you're not including the session token.

Also, can you confirm if by "my ubuntu server" you mean a server running within AWS and using AWS metadata credentials.

Comment: My credentials are currently included in my node app code as shown above in the sever.ja and my Ubuntu system is not running on AWS but in a different provider. In that case, my Lokal Environment and my remote server does not make any difference.